# Not getting correct answers for sum of two double value

Tags: java, double

I have below program:

```
double tax = 180.09;
double gTotal = 277.08;

double total = tax + gTotal;

System.out.println(total);
```

After execution it outputs 457.16999999999996.

After Google search I found that one of the cause for this behavior is that there may be no precise binary representation of the fraction part.

To verify that I tried below:

```
double dNum = 457.17;
System.out.println(dNum);
```

It gave correct output as 457.17. In this case, why it is not printing 457.16999999999996.

Comment: welcome to the floating precision point jungle!!! Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177506/why-do-i-see-a-double-variable-initialized-to-some-value-like-21-4-as-21-3999996)

Comment: There are at least 100 duplicates of this question. Take a look at the related links to the right

Comment: The right solution is to use `BigDecimal` in place of `double`.  As a general rule, it's a bad idea to use a `double` for calculations with amounts of money.

Comment: maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28395232/217324) has a useful answer.  as to *why* the language was designed this way, ask James Gosling.